# hook_install() doesn't seem to work, even though I have disabled and uninstalled module

Tags: database

I'm writing a module that will enable an editor to determine whether a script is available on a specific node, in order to improve page load times.

I need to create a database table to hold an indicator showing, for each node ID, whether the script is available. My code is this.

```
function script_show_schema() { 
    $schema['script_show_enabled'] = array(
        'description' => 'Tracks whether Script Show is enabled for a given node',
        'fields' => array(
            'nid' => array(
                'description' => 'The {node}.nid that has Script Show enabled', 
                'type' => 'int', 
}               'not null' => TRUE, 
                'default' => 0, 
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('nid'),
    ); 
    return $schema;
}
```

I've disabled, then uninstalled, then re-enabled my module through the admin UI, (as opposed to using Drush), but I still don't seem to be able to see my database tables.

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before, but usually the solution seems to be the uninstall thing.

Does anyone have any idea on what is going wrong? I wonder if it's a DB permissions thing. But then, I guess Drupal has root access to the DB in order to create its tables in the first place.

Updates:

I am using version 7.23 of the core.

Here's my .info file:

```
; $Id$ 
name = Script Show
description = "Allows the user to specify that the Maxymiser script will only execute on specific pages"
package = JD Dev Modules
core = 7.x
files[] = script_show.module


flag
```

My entire module is here: [github.com/jamesdesq/script_show](https://github.com/jamesdesq/script_show).

Comment: In which file is located this hook?

Comment: @xurshid29 it's in script_show.install, which is in the root of the module file (so sites/all/modules/custom/script_show)

Comment: try to add another `serial` type field (just for experiment) and change `nid` primary key to that field..

Comment: I can't say that it's a drupal issue.. I think you should include some information to the question: what version of drupal you are using, structure of module files, what `.info` file contains, `.module` file exists or not and so on.. Because, I tried you code and I can see it's creating `script_show_enabled` table..

Comment: you can see that created table [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgjknc317z6uu01/1.png)

Comment: I am not agree with that its a drupal issue... Could you please send me the module you  have created? Issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: have you added hook_install() in your .install file?

Comment: Thanks guys!
@xurshid29 - in answer to your questions: I'm using 7.23, I have a .module file, containing implementations of  hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(), hook_node_view() and hook_form_alter(). I've added the .info file to the main question, above

Comment: @arun - do you need to use hook_install() as well as hook_schema()? I thought simply adding your hook_schema() implementation in your .install file would work OK. But it's entirely possible that I'm wrong.

Comment: @jamesdesq which version of drupal you are using?

Comment: Thanks guys. Just in case you're curious, my entire module is here : https://github.com/jamesdesq/script_show

Comment: @ARUN Version 7.23

Answer (score 0):

The code in your git repo is *not* the same as the code posted here.  Both has syntax errors.  See @ARUN's answer for the bug in the code posted here.

As for the code in the git repo, there are two lines of random junk in it (indicated with red striketroughs below), causing Drupal to crash before the table is created in the database.

[image]

Remove those two lines and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. There is one syntax error at line no:8 (one additional **}**). Remove that and try. It is working.

```
function script_show_schema() { 
  $schema['script_show_enabled'] = array(
    'description' => 'Tracks whether Script Show is enabled for a given node',
    'fields' => array(
        'nid' => array(
            'description' => 'The {node}.nid that has Script Show enabled', 
            'type' => 'int', 
           'not null' => TRUE, 
            'default' => 0, 
        ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('nid'),
  ); 
return $schema;
}
```